# Use character as parameters in table

Tags: html, line-breaks

I have a text string like this:

```
Jenny Lewis . Pretty Bird Sergio Mendes & Brasil 66 . For What it’s 
Worth Petra Magoni feat. Jean-Jacques Milteau & Manu Galvin . Fever 
Emiliana Torrini . Me and Amini Cowboy Junkies . Run for your Life Mira 
Billotte . As I Went out in the Morning Nitin Sawhney feat. Tina Grace 
. October Daze Isobel Campbell . Saturday’s Gone Barbara . Mes 
Hommes...
```

And I want to use the line break character in my string as parameters of my table. I want something like this :

```
Jenny Lewis . Pretty Bird Sergio Mendes & Brasil 66 .
For What it’s Worth Petra Magoni feat. Jean-Jacques Milteau & Manu Galvin .
Fever Emiliana Torrini . Me and Amini Cowboy Junkies . 
Run for your Life Mira Billotte . As I Went out in the Morning Nitin Sawhney feat. 
Tina Grace . October Daze Isobel Campbell . 
Saturday’s Gone Barbara . Mes Hommes...
```

It can be a (\n)  or any other character. At the end of each line there is a line break character.
Someone have an idea?

Comment: Which server side lang are you using? Is there line break information (eg: \n) in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has an incorrect formulation. ( `"...i want to use the line break characte..."` than you've said `"...It can be a (\n) or any other character. ..."` )

You can use tag `</br>`

```html
Jenny Lewis . Pretty Bird Sergio Mendes & Brasil 66 .</br> For What it’s 
Worth Petra Magoni feat. Jean-Jacques Milteau & Manu Galvin .</br> Fever 
Emiliana Torrini . Me and Amini Cowboy Junkies .</br> Run for your Life Mira 
Billotte . As I Went out in the Morning Nitin Sawhney feat.</br> Tina Grace 
. October Daze Isobel Campbell .</br> Saturday’s Gone Barbara . Mes 
Hommes...
```

Comment: Those data are in a variable. I can't change the data itself. I want to do something like this.  <table v-for = data in data ><tr><td> {{data}} </td></tr></table> maybe i should precise that i use VueJS.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain your problem a little more. Is that string being placed inside one column? If so then why don't you make the column a specific width E.g:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <col width="330">
  <col width="80">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jenny Lewis . Pretty Bird Sergio Mendes & Brasil 66 . For What it’s 
Worth Petra Magoni feat. Jean-Jacques Milteau & Manu Galvin . Fever 
Emiliana Torrini . Me and Amini Cowboy Junkies . Run for your Life Mira 
Billotte . As I Went out in the Morning Nitin Sawhney feat. Tina Grace 
. October Daze Isobel Campbell . Saturday’s Gone Barbara . Mes 
Hommes...</td>
    <td>This is under column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is another long string. This is another long string. This is another long string. This is another long string. This is another long string. This is another long string. This is another long string. This is another long string. This is another long string. </td>
    <td>Again this is under column 2... also a long string:Again this is under column 2... also a long string: Again this is under column 2... also a long string: Again this is under column 2... also a long string:  </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>The col width attribute is not supported in HTML5.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Or do you want each one of those to be in separate columns/rows

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i should do the thing like this.

```
<table v-for="piste in details.text_tracks">
    <tr>
        <td>{{details.text_tracks}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

var details.text_tracks = "Jenny Lewis . Pretty Bird Sergio Mendes & 
Brasil 66 .\n For What it’s Worth Petra Magoni feat. Jean-Jacques 
Milteau & Manu Galvin .\n Fever Emiliana Torrini . Me and Amini Cowboy 
Junkies .\n Run for your Life Mira Billotte . As I Went out in the 
Morning Nitin Sawhney feat.\n Tina Grace . October Daze Isobel Campbell 
.\n Saturday’s Gone Barbara . Mes Hommes...\n"
```

This is my full code. I want a table that create cell for each line.

Comment: I want one column and multiples lines one for each line with \n.

Answer (score 0):

**Standalone code**

```js
var details = {};

details.text_tracks = "Jenny Lewis . Pretty Bird Sergio Mendes & Brasil 66 .\n For What it’s Worth Petra Magoni feat. Jean-Jacques Milteau & Manu Galvin .\n Fever Emiliana Torrini . Me and Amini Cowboy Junkies .\n Run for your Life Mira Billotte . As I Went out in the Morning Nitin Sawhney feat.\n Tina Grace . October Daze Isobel Campbell .\n Saturday’s Gone Barbara . Mes Hommes...\n";

details.text_tracks = details.text_tracks.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');

document.getElementById("my-text").innerHTML = details.text_tracks;
```

```html
<div id="my-text">

</div>
```

**Modification in your code**

You should replace \n with `<br>` Use the below code

```
var details.text_tracks = "Jenny Lewis . Pretty Bird Sergio Mendes & 
Brasil 66 .\n For What it’s Worth Petra Magoni feat. Jean-Jacques 
Milteau & Manu Galvin .\n Fever Emiliana Torrini . Me and Amini Cowboy 
Junkies .\n Run for your Life Mira Billotte . As I Went out in the 
Morning Nitin Sawhney feat.\n Tina Grace . October Daze Isobel Campbell 
.\n Saturday’s Gone Barbara . Mes Hommes...\n"

details.text_tracks = details.text_tracks .replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

You can also do this in the server side code before sending it client.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are really asking for, but as far as I understand you would like your text string in one text area or text box.

You could form a text area using HTML by the following code,

```
<th colspan="3" rowspan="9" id="textarea"> 
    <textarea id = "textInput"  rows = "13"  cols = "100">
    </textarea>
</th>
```

Where colspan, rowspan, id, rows and cols can be defined by you.
And in javascript you can use,

```
textarea = document.getElementById('textInput');
textarea.value = 'Jenny Lewis . Pretty Bird Sergio Mendes & Brasil 66 .\n For What it’s Worth Petra Magoni feat. Jean-Jacques Milteau & Manu Galvin .\n Fever......';
```

or...

```
textarea = document.getElementById('textInput');
textarea.value = 'Jenny Lewis . Pretty Bird Sergio Mendes & Brasil 66 .\n';
textarea.value = textarea.value + 'For What it’s Worth Petra Magoni feat. Jean-Jacques Milteau & Manu Galvin .\n';
```

and repeat the textarea.value = textarea.value + 'blablabla \n';

Answer (score 0):

Here you are... right now it calls the function on button click but that can easily be changed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Jenny Lewis . Pretty Bird Sergio Mendes & Brasil 66 .</br> For What it’s Worth Petra Magoni feat. Jean-Jacques Milteau & Manu Galvin .</br> Fever Emiliana Torrini . Me and Amini Cowboy Junkies .</br> Run for your Life Mira Billotte . As I Went out in the Morning Nitin Sawhney feat.</br> Tina Grace . October Daze Isobel Campbell .</br> Saturday’s Gone Barbara . Mes Hommes...;"
    var res = str.split("</br>").join("</td></tr><tr><td>");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=  "<td>" + res + "</td></tr>";
}
</script>

<p>Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<table id="demo">
  <col width="130">
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```